# VBA error runtime 1004: Method 'Range' of object failed

Tags: vba, excel

When I try to run my code i get the error:

> Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

I have searched for different solutions but I have no idea how to solve it, I went through the code a couple of times and still the issue persists.

All this code is in Excel VBA and the range function seems to be the one causing the issue hence why I cannot find what exactly changed which might cause range to be defective.

```
Sub qq()
Dim d(23), LastRow As Integer
Dim c(23) As String
Dim e(23) As Date
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 0 To LastRow
If Range("c" & i).Value = 0.25 And Range("c" & (i + 1)).Value = 0.25 And Range("l" & i).Value = 32 And Range("l" & (i + 1)).Value = 32 Then
c(0) = Range("d" & i).Value
d(0) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max((Range("a" & i).Value), (Range("a" & (i + 1)).Value))
e(0) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("k" & i).Value, Range("k" & (i + 1)).Value)
 ElseIf Range("c" & i).Value = 0.25 And Range("c" & (i + 1)).Value = 0.25 And Range("l" & i).Value = 10 And Range("l" & (i + 1)).Value = 10 Then
c(1) = Range("d" & i).Value
d(1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max((Range("a" & i).Value), (Range("a" & (i + 1)).Value))
e(1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("k" & i).Value, Range("k" & (i + 1)).Value)
 ElseIf Range("c" & i).Value = 0.25 And Range("c" & (i + 1)).Value = 0.25 And Range("l" & i).Value = 2 And Range("l" & (i + 1)).Value = 2 Then
c(2) = Range("d" & i).Value
d(2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max((Range("a" & i).Value), (Range("a" & (i + 1)).Value))
e(2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("k" & i).Value, Range("k" & (i + 1)).Value)
ElseIf Range("c" & i).Value = 0.25 And Range("c" & (i + 1)).Value = 0.25 And Range("l" & i).Value = 3 And Range("l" & (i + 1)).Value = 3 Then
c(3) = Range("d" & i).Value
d(3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max((Range("a" & i).Value), (Range("a" & (i + 1)).Value))
e(3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("k" & i).Value, Range("k" & (i + 1)).Value)
 ElseIf Range("c" & i).Value = 0.25 And Range("c" & (i + 1)).Value = 0.25 And Range("l" & i).Value = 22 And Range("l" & (i + 1)).Value = 22 Then
c(4) = Range("d" & i).Value
d(4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max((Range("a" & i).Value), (Range("a" & (i + 1)).Value))
e(4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("k" & i).Value, Range("k" & (i + 1)).Value)
ElseIf Range("c" & i).Value = 0.25 And Range("c" & (i + 1)).Value = 0.25 And Range("l" & i).Value = 8 And Range("l" & (i + 1)).Value = 8 Or (Range("l" & i).Value = 27 And Range("l" & (i + 1)).Value = 27) Then
c(5) = Range("d" & i).Value
d(5) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max((Range("a" & i).Value), (Range("a" & (i + 1)).Value))
e(5) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("k" & i).Value, Range("k" & (i + 1)).Value)
ElseIf Range("c" & i).Value = 0.25 And Range("c" & (i + 1)).Value = 0.25 And Range("l" & i).Value = 15 And Range("l" & (i + 1)).Value = 15 Or (Range("l" & i).Value = 28 And Range("l" & (i + 1)).Value = 28) Then
c(6) = Range("d" & i).Value
d(6) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max((Range("a" & i).Value), (Range("a" & (i + 1)).Value))
e(6) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("k" & i).Value, Range("k" & (i + 1)).Value)
ElseIf Range("c" & i).Value = 0.25 And Range("c" & (i + 1)).Value = 0.25 And Range("l" & i).Value = 6 And Range("l" & (i + 1)).Value = 6 Then
c(7) = Range("d" & i).Value
d(7) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max((Range("a" & i).Value), (Range("a" & (i + 1)).Value))
e(7) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("k" & i).Value, Range("k" & (i + 1)).Value)
ElseIf Range("c" & i).Value = 0.25 And Range("c" & (i + 1)).Value = 0.25 And Range("l" & i).Value = 4 And Range("l" & (i + 1)).Value = 4 Then
c(8) = Range("d" & i).Value
d(8) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max((Range("a" & i).Value), (Range("a" & (i + 1)).Value))
e(8) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("k" & i).Value, Range("k" & (i + 1)).Value)
ElseIf Range("c" & i).Value = 0.25 And Range("c" & (i + 1)).Value = 0.25 And Range("l" & i).Value = 19 And Range("l" & (i + 1)).Value = 19 Then
c(9) = Range("d" & i).Value
d(9) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max((Range("a" & i).Value), (Range("a" & (i + 1)).Value))
e(9) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("k" & i).Value, Range("k" & (i + 1)).Value)
ElseIf Range("c" & i).Value = 0.25 And Range("c" & (i + 1)).Value = 0.25 And Range("l" & i).Value = 5 And Range("l" & (i + 1)).Value = 5 Then
c(10) = Range("d" & i).Value
d(10) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max((Range("a" & i).Value), (Range("a" & (i + 1)).Value))
e(10) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("k" & i).Value, Range("k" & (i + 1)).Value)
ElseIf Range("c" & i).Value = 0.25 And Range("c" & (i + 1)).Value = 0.25 And Range("l" & i).Value = 9 And Range("l" & (i + 1)).Value = 9 Then
c(11) = Range("d" & i).Value
d(11) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max((Range("a" & i).Value), (Range("a" & (i + 1)).Value))
e(11) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("k" & i).Value, Range("k" & (i + 1)).Value)
ElseIf Range("c" & i).Value = 0.25 And Range("c" & (i + 1)).Value = 0.25 And Range("l" & i).Value = 29 And Range("l" & (i + 1)).Value = 29 Then
c(12) = Range("d" & i).Value
d(12) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max((Range("a" & i).Value), (Range("a" & (i + 1)).Value))
e(12) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("k" & i).Value, Range("k" & (i + 1)).Value)
ElseIf Range("c" & i).Value = 0.25 And Range("c" & (i + 1)).Value = 0.25 And Range("l" & i).Value = 17 And Range("l" & (i + 1)).Value = 17 Then
c(13) = Range("d" & i).Value
d(13) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max((Range("a" & i).Value), (Range("a" & (i + 1)).Value))
e(13) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("k" & i).Value, Range("k" & (i + 1)).Value)
ElseIf Range("c" & i).Value = 0.25 And Range("c" & (i + 1)).Value = 0.25 And Range("l" & i).Value = 13 And Range("l" & (i + 1)).Value = 13 Then
c(14) = Range("d" & i).Value
d(14) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max((Range("a" & i).Value), (Range("a" & (i + 1)).Value))
e(14) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("k" & i).Value, Range("k" & (i + 1)).Value)
ElseIf Range("c" & i).Value = 0.25 And Range("c" & (i + 1)).Value = 0.25 And Range("l" & i).Value = 18 And Range("l" & (i + 1)).Value = 18 Then
c(15) = Range("d" & i).Value
d(15) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max((Range("a" & i).Value), (Range("a" & (i + 1)).Value))
e(15) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("k" & i).Value, Range("k" & (i + 1)).Value)
ElseIf Range("c" & i).Value = 0.25 And Range("c" & (i + 1)).Value = 0.25 And Range("l" & i).Value = 14 And Range("l" & (i + 1)).Value = 14 Or (Range("l" & i).Value = 33 And Range("l" & (i + 1)).Value = 33) Then
c(16) = Range("d" & i).Value
d(16) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max((Range("a" & i).Value), (Range("a" & (i + 1)).Value))
e(16) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("k" & i).Value, Range("k" & (i + 1)).Value)
 ElseIf Range("c" & i).Value = 0.25 And Range("c" & (i + 1)).Value = 0.25 And Range("l" & i).Value = 20 And Range("l" & (i + 1)).Value = 20 Or (Range("l" & i).Value = 21 And Range("l" & (i + 1)).Value = 21) Then
c(17) = Range("d" & i).Value
d(17) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max((Range("a" & i).Value), (Range("a" & (i + 1)).Value))
e(17) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("k" & i).Value, Range("k" & (i + 1)).Value)
 ElseIf Range("c" & i).Value = 0.25 And Range("c" & (i + 1)).Value = 0.25 And Range("l" & i).Value = 11 And Range("l" & (i + 1)).Value = 11 Then
c(18) = Range("d" & i).Value
d(18) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max((Range("a" & i).Value), (Range("a" & (i + 1)).Value))
e(18) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("k" & i).Value, Range("k" & (i + 1)).Value)
ElseIf Range("c" & i).Value = 0.25 And Range("c" & (i + 1)).Value = 0.25 And Range("l" & i).Value = 12 And Range("l" & (i + 1)).Value = 12 Then
c(19) = Range("d" & i).Value
d(19) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max((Range("a" & i).Value), (Range("a" & (i + 1)).Value))
e(19) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("k" & i).Value, Range("k" & (i + 1)).Value)
ElseIf Range("c" & i).Value = 0.25 And Range("c" & (i + 1)).Value = 0.25 And Range("l" & i).Value = 25 And Range("l" & (i + 1)).Value = 25 Then
c(20) = Range("d" & i).Value
d(20) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max((Range("a" & i).Value), (Range("a" & (i + 1)).Value))
e(20) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("k" & i).Value, Range("k" & (i + 1)).Value)

 Else

End If

Next

MsgBox (c(0))



End Sub
```

Comment: You should really learn both to include the error message as text and how to take screenshots... and create a shortest code that can replicate your issue.

Comment: Do you know how to step through code (e.g. see http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)? If you can do that and narrow down the exact line that'd help a lot. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You are starting your loop with `i` at 0 which does not exist as a row in the sheet. The first cell in the sheet is `(1,1)` i.e. `A1`

So your: `Range("l" & i)` is `Range("L0")`, at start of loop, which doesn't exist, hence your error.

Your loop needs to start at at least 1 i.e. `For i = 1 To LastRow`

Comment: After I created an array and stored data according to current conditions I ran another loop running on the entire array, loop condition as long as CI is different than zero paste in the second third cell as long as the condition is fulfilled why the loop did not want according to the code I set for it and how can I create one There will not be one order under the two that existed how to do according to the jump of I